# Sitecore invalid hash value seems to be failing. there are multiple hash queries in the query string

Tags: media-library, fxm

```
ERROR MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered. 
The expected hash value: **3B2EEFF3A17529C1E25F9A4C6136A7EC**. 
Media URL: /-/media/images/features/navigation/support/warranty-700x578.ashx?h=116&la=en&w=117&lm=636911248440000000&hash=**3B2EEFF3A17529C1E25F9A4C6136A7EC**&hash=**3B2EEFF3A17529C1E25F9A4C6136A7EC**, 
Referring URL: https://xxxxxx.com/
```

I am trying to establish why there are two hash values in the query string, the page that the requests are coming from are not in Sitecore but it does use FXM.

Comment: And what is the code of the component which is used by FXM? How does it render the image?

Comment: looks like this isn't happening on just the fxm model but all over the site 
this is what we're using to render the images Model.Image.Render(cssClass: "a-image a-image--product", editable:false).ToString())

Comment: Can you check if you have maybe doubled processor in `/sitecore/adminshowconfig.aspx` of class `ProtectedImageLinkRenderer`?

Comment: Were you able to track down the issues? Even I do see the same issue in our logs except for the fact that I get two different hash values.